# How can I send commands from raspberry pi model 3B to Seriously Pro 3 Flight controller?

Tags: quadcopter, raspberry-pi, python, robotics-library, flight-controller

I am trying to make a quadcopter that receives commands from my android mobile phone. I currently have the following:

1. Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running on Raspbian.
2. Pi Camera
3. Seriously Pro F3 Flight Controller

I am planning on using bluetooth to send commands to my raspberry pi, but I am unable to figure out how to send commands from the raspberry pi to the flight controller. I am thus asking, how do I send commands (those of movement and throttle) from my raspberry pi to the flight controller.

Link to Flight Controller Documentation:
http://seriouslypro.com/files/SPRacingF3-Manual-latest.pdf

This is the project I am trying to make:
http://www.instructables.com/id/The-Drone-Pi/

This project is made with a MultiWii flight controller, while I want to make it with a SPF3 Flight Controller, I don't know how to approach accomplishing it.

I'm asking a similar question:
[Quadcopter controlled by Raspberry Pi](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/13883/quadcopter-controlled-by-raspberry-pi)

but with a SPF3 Flight controller rather than CC3D Flight Controller and with a little more explanation of terms.

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Mohit Garg, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: I'm sorry @Mohit Garg but we still don't have enough information about what your problem is. Please explain what you have already tried and describe what happened when you tried it.

Comment: Also please put a link to the documentation of the flight controller.

Comment: How about now @MarkBooth

Comment: Thanks @MohitGarg your edit does make your question better, but it still doesn't isn't clear what your question is. Al the moment it looks like you are asking a rather broad question about what to do next rather than asking how to solve a specific problem. It would also be good to say what happened when you connected the SP F3 and the Raspberry Pi with a USB cable, installed the Silicon Labs CP210 drivers and tried to run the Cleanflight Configurator tool, as the instructions suggest.

Comment: @MarkBooth I am asking what to do next since I don't understand most of the documentation as I am new to quadcopters and flight.

Comment: I added link to a similar question in the question

Comment: Thanks for adding the link to the other question. Since the answer to that question also answers this question, I will close this as a duplicate.

Comment: The other question answers this with a CC3D controller, while I am looking for an answer with a Seriously Pro F3 Controller.